# ¿Por qué no deja de aparecer mensajes en el vmware en una maquina virtual linux?

Tags: ssh, centos, vmware

Buenos días con todos,

He instalado en CentOS Stream 9 en vmware, pero noto que en el vmware no paran de aparece mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este comportamiento no repite si acceso a la máquina virtual por ssh.